# Fix HardFault on stm32h7 with arm native toolchain, with CubeIDE it works fine

Tags: c++, toolchain, stm32cubeide, compiler-bug, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I have the following function that serializes the RTC data of the microcontroller:

```cpp
string serialize() const {
    return "\"counter\": " + to_string(counter);
}
```

Besides the clear mistake using this serialization in a microcontroller is,I have the following issue, when compiling with the native arm-toolchain I get a HardFault at runtime when running `"\"counter: " + to_string(counter)`, note that with just that it crashes.
But when I compile using stm32CubeIDE toolchain, it runs fine. Is this a bug on the arm compiler?

For reference the compiler for CubeIDE can be found under `<your-install-dir>/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.linux64_1.1./tools/bin`.

I reckon this compiler is different because cubeIDE passes some flags like -fcyclomatic-complexity, which are not available on the native arm compiler.
However I would expect the code snippet to behave the same way with both compilers.

Also the code runs fine on Ubuntu using g++, so it looks like an issue on the arm compiler

Changing the line to:

```cpp
return string{"counter:"} + to_string(counter);
```

doesn't cause this HardFault

Comment: I tested with a STM32H7A3ZI-Q board, the issue isn't here. Can you post a reproducible and complete example ?